# Prove that the min and max of 2 continuous function are continuous

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions the so are $\min⁡\{f(x),g(x)\}$ and $\max⁡\{f(x),g(x)\}$

I know this is true when $f$ and $g$ are not intersect each other, then I can compare them. However, I don't know how to prove it's true when they are intersect.

Comment: You write this is in calculus/proof-writing. Do you know $\epsilon, \delta$ limits and continuity? Is this how you are expecting to write this up?

Comment: You can prove that $\min,\,\max \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous. Then the continuity of compositions of continuous functions does the rest.

Comment: A different hint: $\max(f,g)=\frac12(f+g+|f-g|)$.

Comment: @mixedmath yes, I'm expecting a ϵ-δ proof.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I don't think I have learn that technique yet

Comment: @dls your hint may be true, but I can't use it until it have been proven in class or by myself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let $h(x) = \min\{f(x),g(x)\}$. Suppose $x_0$ is such that $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$. We want to show $h$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Take $\epsilon > 0$, then there is a $\delta_f$ so that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ for $|x-x_0| < \delta_f$, and similarly for $g$ and some $\delta_g$ (with the same $\epsilon$).

Use this, and the fact that $h(x_0) = f(x_0) = g(x_0)$ to show that $|h(x) - h(x_0)| < \epsilon$ whether $h(x) = f(x)$ or $h(x) = g(x)$ as long as $|x-x_0| < \delta$ for some $\delta$.

Comment: and you can do the same to max{f(x),g(x)}?

Comment: Yep, the exact same argument will work.

Comment: This is true for finitely many continuous functions, correct? How can you show that this does not hold for infinitely many continuous functions? @BaronVT

Comment: Also, what is your reasoning for setting $x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$? Does this prove the statement generally, or only for the case in which we have an $x_0$ with this property?

Comment: In the case there is no such $x_0$, you can show that $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$ (or vice-versa) and so $\max(f,g) = g$ (or $f$), which is known to be continuous a priori. (note that in OP's question, they note that they already know how to handle this case, so I omitted it from my original answer)

For finitely many functions, you can write $\max(f,g,h)$ etc. as a composition of continuous functions $\max, f, g, h,$ etc.

In the case of infinitely many functions, more things can go wrong: for instance, let $f_n(x) = nx$, then $\max_n(f_n) = \infty$ for most values of $x$.

Comment: @baronVT 'and the fsct that $h(x_0)=f(x_0)=g(x_0)$'? I don't see how you may say this

Comment: This is by assumption, if it is not true, the proof is trivial (do you see why?)