# Covering a Set with Balls in a Continuously Varying Way

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Say $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $X \subset U$ is compact. I want to find a number $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $x \in X$, $B_\epsilon(x) \subset U$. My plan is to define a function $\rho : X \to [0.\infty)$, where $\rho(x) = \sup\{\epsilon \in (0,1] : B_\epsilon(x) \subset U\}$. If this function is continuous, we can find its minimum because $X$ is compact, and then we're set. But is this function actually continuous?

Comment: Is $U$ itself an open ball?  If $U$ is not convex, there might not be an open ball based at a point in $X$ which is a strict subset of $U$ and contains all of $X$.  Why do you want a ball $B_\varepsilon(x)$ and not just an open set containing $X$ that is itself a subset of $U$?

Comment: @Renard I'm not requiring that any single open ball contain all of $X$, just that there's a single radius such that all the balls of that radius around each point in $X$ lie inside $U$. My end goal is to show that $U$ contains an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $X$ for some $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [continuity of the distance function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944659/distance-to-a-closed-set-is-continuous) $d(x,U^c)$ as a function of $x\in \mathbb R^n$ is a routine exercise. Restricting $x\in X$ only has the effect of [making this function *positive*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/a-and-b-disjoint-a-compact-and-b-closed-implies-there-is-positive-distance-bet) (because $X$ is (closed) compact and contained in (open) $U$).

The only additional ingredient to consider is the limitation of $\rho(x)$ to take values that are at most $1$.  So the Reader is asked to show that:

$$ \rho(x) := \min \{1,d(x,U^c)\} $$

is [accordingly a continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530135/prove-that-the-min-and-max-of-2-continuous-function-are-continuous) of $x\in X$.