# Question about Lebesgue Number Lemma proof

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I know there are some similar questions already on MSE, but none answers my question, since all of them refer to a proof that defines a different function $f(x)$.

Let me first state the version of proof I'm referring to:

> We first note that $K(x, \lambda) \subseteq U \iff d(x, U^C) >
>  \lambda$. Therefore $K(x, \lambda) \subseteq U_i$ for at least one $i
>  \iff \text{max}_i \{d(x,U_i^C)\} > \lambda$. Let $U_1, U_2, \ldots,
>  U_n$ be a finite subcover of cover  $\mathcal{U}$. Then the function
> $f: X \to [0, +\infty)$, defined as $f(x) := \text{max}_i
>  \{d(x,U_i^C)\}$ is continuous and has a minimum. This minimum is
> greater than $0$, since the sets  $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ cover $X$. It
> follows from here that $\lambda := \text{min} \{ f(x); x \in X \}$ is
> a suitable choice for Lebesgue covering number of the cover
> $\mathcal{U}$.

My main question is why $f$ is continuous? I certainly do not find it obvious. Then also, why is the minimum strictly positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is a maximum of finitely many continuous functions, and is, as such, continuous.

Also, the function is a maximum of non-negative functions and is therefore non-negative.

Comment: Why is the maximum of continuous functions continuous?

Comment: @Matthew https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530135/prove-that-the-min-and-max-of-2-continuous-function-are-continuous

Comment: thank you, I understand it now.