# Upper semi continuity approximation continuous functions

Tags: metric-spaces, harmonic-functions

I am currently studying *Potential Theory of the Complex Plane* written by Ransford. In his early section of his second chapter, he introduces the notion of upper semi continuous functions (u.s.c) and he proves a theorem of approximating such functions by continuous ones, Theorem 2.1.3, having the assumption that the u.s.c function $u$ should be bounded above.

Next, he presents an exercise which states that this condition can be removed by using a distinct test function, defined as follows.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $u\colon X\rightarrow [-\infty,+\infty)$ be an u.s.c. For $n\geq 0$, define the
$$F_n\doteqdot \{x\in X\colon u(x)\geq n\}$$
$$\psi_n(x)\doteqdot \max(0,1-n dist(x,F_n))\qquad (x\in X)$$

Then one can show that the sum $\sum_{n=0}\psi_n$ converges locaaly uniformly to a continous function $\psi$ with $\psi\geq u$.

Now, the problem is first I cannot even vizualize how this series to such function. I thought of concrete examples of upper semi continuous functions, like
$$u(x)=x \text{ for }0\leq x<1\qquad u(x)=2 \text{ for }1\leq x<+\infty$$
Then, computing easily the $F_n$ and $\psi_n$, the result is validated. I cannot think of a general way to approach its proof however. Any help shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact lies here to see that the exercise desires **locally uniform convergence**. In particular, let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$. By a Proposition it is true that $u$ is bounded above on $K$, so there exists an index $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$, so that
$$u(x)< N_0\qquad\forall x\in K\,.$$
In particular, we have that $K\cap F_n=\emptyset$ for every $n\geq N_0$,. Since the definition of distance says that $\operatorname{dist}(x,\emptyset)=+\infty$ then it is true that by definition of $\phi_n$
$$\phi_n(x)=0 \qquad\forall x\in K\qquad \forall n\geq N_0.$$
In particular, the above series is apparently a finite sum of functions or the partial sums of the series is an eventually constant sequence of functions. Hence it trivially converges uniformly on $K$ and therefore converges in $X$ to a function $\psi\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
We have to prove that $\psi$ is continuous. Since the distance function is continuous, it is clear that $\psi_n$ is a maximum of continuous functions, and henceforth continuous. See a similar question answered in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530135/prove-that-the-min-and-max-of-2-continuous-function-are-continuous).

So for each $n$, the function $\psi_n$ is continuous. Since $\psi$ consists of **finite sum of continuous** functions, it is also continuous.
\par Finally $\psi(x)\geq u(x)$ for every $x\in X$. Fix an $x\in X$. Since $u$ does not take $+\infty$ value, then there exists a $n_x\in\mathbb{N}$ so that
$$n_x-1\leq u(x)< n_x\,.$$
In particular, $x\in F_n$ for all $n=0,\dots n_x-1$ while $x\notin F_n$ for all $n\geq n_x$. So
$$\operatorname{dist}(x,F_n)=0\qquad\forall n=0,\dots,n_x-1$$
and therefore
$$\psi_n(x)\equiv 1\qquad \forall n=0,\dots,n_x-1\,.$$
However, by the definition of $\psi$,
$$\psi(x)\geq n_x>u\,.$$
As $x\in X$ was arbitrary the result is proven.